# Find $f'(x)$ if $f(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-xy^2}dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals

Find $f'(x)$ if $$f(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-xy^2}dy$$

I know the property (though if anyone could refer me to a proof that would be great):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy = \int_{a}^{\infty} f_x'(x,y)dy $$

In our case, the $a$ term is a function. Let $g(x) = x$ then $f(x, g(x))$. By the chain rule:

$$f'(x, g(x)) = f'(x, g(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$$

I now find the terms:

$$f'(x, g(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-xy^2}dy = \int_{x}^{\infty}-y^2e^{-xy^2}dy $$

$$\frac{\partial f}{ \partial g} = \frac{d}{dg} \int_{g}^{\infty} e^{-gy^2}dy = \int_{g}^{\infty}-g^2 e^{-gy^2}dy ???$$

The second one I am not so sure how to deal with, could someone please clarify if this approach works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $x>0$ (otherwise, the integral that defines $f(x)$ diverges).

By the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), you have\begin{align}f'(x)&=-e^{-xx^2}+\int_x^\infty-y^2e^{-xy^2}\,\mathrm dy\\&=-e^{-x^3}-\int_x^\infty y^2e^{-xy^2}\,\mathrm dy.\end{align}

Comment: Why is it when $f'(x)$ the $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy^2}dy$ disappears?

Comment: The given answer is $-e^{-x^3} - \int_{a}^{\infty} y^2 e^{-xy^2}dy$ does this make sense?

Comment: How can the answer be $-e^{-x^3}-\int_a^\infty y^2e^{-xy^2}\,\mathrm dy$ when there is no $a$ in the question?

Comment: Did you mean $-e^{-x^3}-\int_x^\infty y^2e^{-xy^2}\,\mathrm dy$?

Comment: Anyway, I introduced unnecessary complications in my original answer. I've replaced it by a simpler one.

Comment: They broke up the original integral with $a$ as an arbitrary constant $>$ ... their given answer is still unclear in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to view this situation:

Let $f(x_1,x_2) = \int_{x_1}^{\infty} e^{-x_2y^2}dy$. So what you are looking for is ${dg \over dx}$ where $g(x) =  f(x,x)$. By the chain
rule this is
$${\partial f \over \partial x_1}(x,x) + {\partial f \over \partial x_2}(x,x)$$
You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get that the first term is $-e^{-x^3}$, and then differentiate under the integral sign to get that the second term is $- \int_{x}^{\infty} y^2e^{-x_2y^2}dy$. I'll leave the details to you. The end result will therefore be
$$-e^{x^3} - \int_{x}^{\infty} y^2e^{-xy^2}dy$$